# Month wise cumulative total in column

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-tablix

I need cumulative aggregate after each column for my report. I have a dataset with following data samples.

### **ProductName** **Transdate** **Quantity**

1. A           21-Nov-13      100
2. A           1-Nov-13        50
3. A           1-Dec-13        40
4. A           1-Jan-13       150
5. B           11-Nov-13       30
6. B           2-Dec-13        20
7. B           13-Dec-13       10
8. B           12-Jan-13       80

I want a report which look like below. That means Product wise each month total and Cumulative total. I am able to get month wise total value. Only need suggestion for month wise cumulative total.

**

### Product Nov'13 Cumulative Total Dec'13 Cumulative Total Jan'13 Cumulative Total

## **

1. A   150 150 40  190 150 340
2. B   30  30  30  60  80  140

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the proper textbox use RunningValue function: `=RunningValue(Fields!Quantity.Value,SUM,"Category1")`:
[image]

And your report will display values as follows:
[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot.. It is working...I have used this earlier but it was not working on that time as I didn't choose the right group column for this...

Comment: No problem, I'm glad that it works. If it was that, what you looked for, please mark it as answer.